# Python regular expression could not get replace whole line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace particular area in my text line.
I used python regular expression sub syntax

```
import re
str='WALL = "W101"'
s=re.sub('WALL = "(.*)"','100',str)
print(s)
```

it prints only `100` but 
I expect the whole line `WALL = "100"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider additional capturing group for the first substring:

```
str = 'WALL = "W101"'
s = re.sub(r'^(WALL =\s*)"(.*)"', r'\1"100"', str)
print(s)
```

The output:

```
WALL = "100"
```

`\1` points to the first captured group withing a regular expression

Comment: Also, while not strictly necessary here, a raw string should be used for the regex too, as for *every* regex in Python. It's just too easy to tweak the definition and suddenly end up with an ASCII escape instead of a regex escape and now everything breaks in non-intuitive ways.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, of course, just missed it unintentionally(just human factor). I always use raw string mark `r'...'`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
import re
str = 'WALL = "W101"'
s = re.sub(r'(?<=WALL = ")[^"]+', '100', str)
print(s)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        : start lookbehind, makes sure we have the following before the match
  WALL = "  : literally
)           : end lookbehind
[^"]+       : 1 or more character that is NOT a double quote
```